# Magento Category Pagination URLs

Tags: category, url, filter, seo, pagination

I want to create pagination on my Category pages. I have added this too the footer and configured it via the config and it shows up as expected.

[image: Pagination]

Looks great at first sight, however when I select a different page, for example the 4th page. I get redirected to a link like. https://www.example.com/en/mycategory/where/p/4/

This page gives a 404 error. https://www.example.com/en/category4?p=4

Works fine, I can't seem to be able to change the URL structure anywhere. The first idea which comes to mind is to use htaccess rewrites. But this will get nasty very soon if I am also going to add filters.

Which generate links such as https://www.example.com/en/mycategory/where/dir/asc/order/price/

And changing the amount of products per page generate a link like
https://www.example.com/en/mycategory/where/limit/30/
Which all give 404 errors.

This will become a mess to do via htaccess if I ever want to make these combinable.

What place should I look to figure out the URL structure, or where should I activate to accept this url structure? (I prefer to be able to change it because this looks like bad SEO)

Since categories can have subcategories, a link can also have more subdivision before the "/where/" making htaccess even worse.
URL: https://example.com/en/mycategory/mysubcategory/where/p/5

Edit: I tried the following htaccess code, which is supposed to be recursive, but I get 500 internal server errrors.

## Turn the slashed URL into query strings

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/where/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ $1/where/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

## Remove the "/where/" from the url

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/where/?$ $1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

(I'd prefer a 301 redirect because of SEO reasons, don't want my pagerank splitting up.)

Comment: do you have any seo related extension that affects the filtering and paging. Normally the paging should return urls with `?p=4` not `/p/4`.

Comment: I have some old ManaPro extensions which used to do that. They messed up filtering links indeed. I deactivated them (uninstalling them crashed the site), so weird that they would still affect URL rewrites. Feels like those old crappy modules are still being called here and there.

However I think it might be easier to use the htaccess approach since I am not fully aware of all the modules functions in this installation since I am not the original developer.

Comment: Seems like my htaccess code is correct. Just had to remove the space before the R=301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like my htaccess code is correct. Just had to remove the space before the R=301

Turn the slashed URL into query strings

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/where/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ $1/where/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Remove the "/where/" from the url

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/where/?$ $1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```